# Error while running code in iOS, Getting Ionic HTTP Failure in Response

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I developed my application in `ionic 3` and my back-end is `PHP PDO` , my app is working perfectly in Android and all the web services are getting called perfectly.

I have imported my code in Mac Book and generated in Xcode. when I run that code in simulator API are not getting called and shows error as `HTTP failure Response from unknown URL 0 Unknown Error`.

I have already added white list Plugin in iOS
 I have already added CSP in my index.html file
 API are getting called in Safari Browser perfectly but not in simulator and real device.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your PHP backend have `CORS` enabled?

Comment: yes it has enabled in php

Comment: header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

Answer (score 0):

I have Degraded ionic web view for ios and that worked for me.